# Two Apple IDs - one for business and one for personal

Tags: apple-id

Is it possible to have two apple IDs on one device?  I own a business and have contracted iOS developers to create an app.  I set up an Apple ID to use for the company and started using it to create a developer account for them to use to put the app in the App Store.  That way the control of the app is with the company, not with the contracted developer.  When I went to turn on two-step authentication I wasn’t able to because my devices are set to my personal Apple ID.  I would really prefer to not give the programmers access to my personal account.  So, is there anyway to make this happen using the same device with the two Apple ids?

Comment: There are probably going to be three next questions - be sure to not keep chaniging this one question with edits - just ask a follow on question and post a link to my answer and I will see it next time I log in (and maybe someone else will answer the next one - like how to choose which devices are TFA and which account uses cellular second step to validate a log in request - you can't have one device do both...)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can [split accounts on one device](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378469/can-i-use-different-apple-id-for-music-on-catalina) and this is just about the only case where I would say you would want to make a second AppleID.

1. Just be really careful when you sign in - in general don't accept or enter the AppleID in any set up screen as that places the first AppleID in all the slots. Decline the easy set up and choose app by app which you want to use for [App Store](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/345278/using-two-apple-ids-on-one-mac), for iCloud, for messaging, email, etc...
2. You will run into device limitations for Two factor and Two Step auth - [watch out, Apple had both and they are easy to confuse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375659/2fa-for-multiple-apple-ids-on-same-device) and don't do the same thing or meet the same requirements.

Comment: Thanks bmike!  I have an older iPhone that I don't use anymore.  I just put it on a charger because it has been sitting in a drawer.  I'm going to see if I can sign out of my personal ID and sign in with my business ID.  Do you think that will work?  It does not have a phone number assigned to it.

Comment: Sure, but when it fails you will be locked out so be sure you have a rescue email or phone number if you don’t have at least two iOS devices for second push auth.  @MichaelKooreman